# Browser agnostic C++ DOM interface

Tags: c++, dom, cross-browser

When programming in C++ against the browser's [DOM](http://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=1&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2FDOM%2F&ei=eUhrSaTCDpyY9QSMr5imBw&usg=AFQjCNH0daWhsLwlt2sAqQJ71Vx8WtrHug&sig2=9eYS8DOTG8VOj3tJSKjyvg) each engine has a different set of interfaces, IE has the COM based [MSHTML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752279(VS.85).aspx), Mozilla has the [XPCOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPCOM) based [Gecko DOM](http://www.xulplanet.com/references/xpcomref/ifaces/nsIDOMNSHTMLElement.html) etc.

Is there a common API that has [adapters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) for major browsers (and versions)?

---

As a clarification, the application in question is a desktop application written in C++ which interacts with browsers, currently we have separate code bases for support of IE and Mozilla and I'm trying to reduce duplications of logic and allow adding new browsers with less effort.

A concrete example can be getting the innerHTML property of an HTML element.

```
// Firefox
nsAutoString html;
nsCOMPtr<nsIDOMNSHTMLElement> elem = do_QueryInterface(obj);
if (elem)
    elem->GetInnerHTML(html); 

// IE
CComBSTR html;
MSHTML::IHTMLElementPtr elem = obj;
if (elem) 
     elem->get_innerHTML(&html);
```

Comment: Moonlight is as you say a Silverlight implementation, just thought that they probably have the same issue as you do; interaction with browsers of different versions. So therefore I would guess they have adapters for the different browsers that may be reusable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your best bet seems to be to define your own interface and write different adapters. In the likeliness that your C++ code won't be employing all DOM traversing capabilities, your interface will only have to define a compact set of traversal functions.

As a bonus of defining your own interface, you can easily write a mock adapter for your unit testing.

Answer (score 1):

I've never seen one.  For my software, I simple wrote the extension in Firefox's javascript, and then created an Internet Explorer BHO (which I haven't finished yet).

Answer (score 0):

Moonlight is released under LGPL, they may have something usable for you, if the licensing is ok.

Comment: What is moonlight? I see that there's a Mono implementation of Silverlight with that name but that doesn't seem to be relevant here.

Answer (score -6):

Any reason why it has to be C++? Can't you use jQuery? Or something like http://webkit.org/blog/156/queryselector-and-queryselectorall/ in WebKit might do the trick..